# Small leaks on cold water supply

Tags: plumbing, leaks

I am in the process of replacing my reverse osmosis (RO) system.  Everything went OK until when I installed the feed water supply provided by the RO company.

I installed the provided feed water supply then installed the existing cold water supply line above it.   I didn’t see leaks right away but I put a thick piece of cardboard just in case and left it overnight.

When I woke up this morning I do see just a small water line (picture) and when I run my finger around the cold supply line I see some water on my finger.  I previously attempted to remove the supply line, put some Teflon/plumber’s tape around the threading of the feed water supply, then tightened it.  But each time I see the same thing.   Just very little almost negligible leak.

I’ve attached pics - screenshot of the feed water installation and my under the sink where the small leak on the cardboard is circled.

Can I just leave it alone and install anyway?

Feed adapter taken from the manufacturer's installation video:
[image: feed water adapter]

My installation showing the location of the leak on the cardboard:
[image: my install with leak on cardboard circled]

Comment: here is the feed water adapter provided by the factory (screenshot taken from their installation video). https://imgur.com/a/vwCddNv

Comment: You've asked one question: "Can I just leave it alone and install anyway?" Sure! It's your house. If you don't care about that little drip slowly eating away the bottom of your cabinet and eventually working its way into the floor, sub floor, and whatever is below it, then just leave it. Of course, you probably do care, so you'll want to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lose connection somewhere. Go back and tighten very one. Also tighten the nut on the valve stem for the shutoff valve as they can leak a bit after being operated. You should't be using Teflon tape on the water supply. There's a seal in that fitting and you could be hindering that seal by using the tape. You also don't need the tape on compression fittings.